# Going from one text box to another by keyboard shortcuts

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I wanna change the content of many text boxes. Currently I use Type tool, edit one, click move tool, Type tool and edit the next.

I know there is an easier way, but I forgot it. Like holding cmd in Type tool or similarly.

Anyone able to help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Type, Hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then click the next text area.

You can also type, click the √ mark in the **control bar** across the top of the screen, Then click the next text box.

Comment: I might do it wrong, but that only adds a break in the text. And "clicking" the next text area provides me with the Move tool to move the current text area

Comment: You have to use the **Enter** key, not the **Return** key. They operate differently.

Comment: +1 this was bugging me too; I thought it might work in AI too, but it didn't. After googling I found its the **Esc** key in AI. If only PS & AI were written by the same company, then they might be a little more consistent.

Comment: in AI, you can simply hold the Command/Ctrl key and click, then release and click the next text to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Enter

Was annoying me for a very long time now it makes a tedious task so much quicker